# Searching a NSArray for the nearest number(s)

Tags: objective-c, search, nsarray

Is there an easy way to search an `NSArray` of numbers to find the nearest (or exact if it exists) matches to a user-input number?

Say I have an array like this: `7, 23, 4, 11, 18, 2`, and the user enters `5`.

The program returns the three nearest values in descending order of closeness: `4, 7, 2`, and **most importantly** gives the `NSArray` index of the three objects: `2, 0, 5`.

Comment: I think the easiest way will be to look for the minimun number, remove it, and look for the minimun number again, etc.

Comment: I started by writing a for loop that tests each number, but I quickly realized that I wouldn't be able to get the index of the objects from the original array.  Finding that index is very important for my actual program - what I posted here is a simple example so I could learn the theory

Comment: it should be pretty simple to track back the original index of the number that you find, but you can do that without modifying the array. Say you find the min, you keep its index (thats your first number out of the three), then instead of removing it, you can replace it with the max number - this way, you dont change your array....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: see below for a better solution than my first one.

Here's a solution using NSDictionary wrappers for each number and its index, with sorting using a comparator block. It probably doesn't scale very well, but it gets the job done.

```
static NSString *const kValueKey = @"value";
static NSString *const kIndexKey = @"index";

+ (void)searchArray:(NSArray *)array forClosestValuesTo:(int)value resultValues:(NSArray **)values resultIndexes:(NSArray **)indexes
{
    NSMutableArray *searchObjs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];

    [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [searchObjs addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:obj, kValueKey, [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:idx], kIndexKey, nil]];
    }];

    [searchObjs sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSUInteger d1 = ABS([[obj1 objectForKey:kValueKey] intValue] - value);
        NSUInteger d2 = ABS([[obj2 objectForKey:kValueKey] intValue] - value);
        if (d1 == d2) { return NSOrderedSame; }
        if (d1 <  d2) { return NSOrderedAscending; }
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }];

    NSArray *results = [searchObjs subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];

    if (values) {
        *values = [results valueForKey:kValueKey];
    }

    if (indexes) {
        *indexes = [results valueForKey:kIndexKey];
    }
}
```

Update: here's an updated solution that sorts a C array of indexes, eliminating the need for NSDictionary wrappers

```
static NSString *const kValueKey = @"value";
static NSString *const kArrayKey = @"array";

int
CSCompareIndexes(void *data, const void *value1, const void *value2)
{
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *)data;

    NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:kArrayKey];
    int valueToFind = [[dict objectForKey:kValueKey] intValue];

    int index1 = *(int *)value1;
    int index2 = *(int *)value2;

    NSNumber *num1 = [array objectAtIndex:index1];
    NSNumber *num2 = [array objectAtIndex:index2];

    return ABS([num1 intValue] - valueToFind) - ABS([num2 intValue] - valueToFind);
}

void
CSSearchNumberArray(NSArray *array, int valueToFind, NSArray **resultValues, NSArray **resultIndexes)
{
    NSInteger numValues = [array count];

    NSUInteger *indexes = malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * numValues);
    assert(indexes);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numValues; i++) {
        indexes[i] = i;
    }

    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:array, kArrayKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:valueToFind], kValueKey, nil];
    qsort_r(indexes, numValues, sizeof(NSUInteger), (void *)data, CSCompareIndexes);

    NSMutableArray *tmpValues  = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3],
                   *tmpIndexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        [tmpValues addObject:[array objectAtIndex:indexes[i]]];
        [tmpIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexes[i]]];
    }

    if (resultValues) {
        *resultValues = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tmpValues];
    }

    if (resultIndexes) {
        *resultIndexes = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tmpIndexes];
    }

    free(indexes);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

    NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray array];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        [test addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(arc4random() % 100)]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Searching: %@", test);

    NSArray *values, *indexes;
    CSSearchNumberArray(test, 50, &values, &indexes);

    NSLog(@"Values: %@", values);
    NSLog(@"Indexes: %@", indexes);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually works perfectly - Thank you so much! I would have never figured it out by myself

Comment: IMO, there is no need for the dictionaries. ISTM they are expensive overkill. If you have the index, you automatically have the number it indexes, so there is already an association.

Answer (score 2):

Sort the existing array of values "indirectly", using an array of indexes, and sorting by the "distance" to the search value. The first three items after the sort are the "nearest" values.

Example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NearestSearcher : NSObject { }
+ (NSArray *) searchNearestValuesOf: (int) value inArray: (NSArray *) values;
@end

@implementation NearestSearcher

+ (NSArray *) searchNearestValuesOf: (int) value inArray: (NSArray *) values
{
    // set up values for indexes array
    NSMutableArray *indexes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: values.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.count; i++)
        [indexes addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]];

    // sort indexes 
    [indexes sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) 
     {
         int num1 = abs([[values objectAtIndex: [obj1 intValue]] intValue] - value);
         int num2 = abs([[values objectAtIndex: [obj2 intValue]] intValue] - value);

         return (num1 < num2) ? NSOrderedAscending : 
                (num1 > num2) ? NSOrderedDescending : 
                                NSOrderedSame;
     }];

    return [indexes subarrayWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
}
@end


// DEMO

#define NUM_VALUES 20

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // DEMO SETUP

    // set up values array with random values
    NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: NUM_VALUES];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++)
        [values addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: arc4random() % 200]];

    // display values array
    for (int i = 0; i < values.count; i++)
        NSLog(@"%2d: %4d", i, [[values objectAtIndex: i] intValue]);

    // get a random value for x
    int x = arc4random() % 200;

    // METHOD INVOCATION

    NSArray *results = [NearestSearcher searchNearestValuesOf: x inArray: values];

    // SHOW RESULTS

    NSLog(@"------------------------");

    NSLog(@"x: %d", x);
    for (NSNumber *num in results)
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", num, [values objectAtIndex: [num intValue]]);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you only return a range of 0-3? ( NSMakeRange(0, 3) )

Answer (score 1):

The naive method would be to search the source array for `5`, increment the found count and store the appropriate information if found, then search for `4` and `6`, etc.

A second method would be to keep a sorted copy of the source array:
`2, 4, 7, 11, 18, 23`

then use `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` to find the first number greater than `5` in that array, then compare that number with its left neighbor, to see which is closer to `5`:

`(7-5) < (5-4) ? storeinfo(7) : storeinfo(4)`

If the left neighbor wins, store its info, then compare *its* left neighbor with the original greater-than-five number:

`(7-5) < (5-2) ? storeinfo(7) : storeinfo(2)`

But if the right side wins, compare its right neighbor with the loser:

`(11-5) < (5-2) ? storeinfo(11) : storeinfo(2)`

You should only need to do three comparisons in this case, and you'll need to decide whether you want to use `<` or `<=`. Your second array is just n*ptr size, so it's not a huge space growth.

Comment: + 1 for second method, you may want to use abs() so that the difference is positive whether or not you subtract a greater value. I'd assume that if you were doing this dynamically, you wouldn't know whether to use 7-5 or 5-7.

Comment: At first I had the same thought, but as long as you're operating on a sorted array *and* you made sure to find the first entry that was greater than the target number, you can always know that the entry you found is greater than `5`, and the entry to its left is less than or equal to `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework question?  An easy way to code this by utilizing apis is to generate an array called `distances` containing the distance from each original number, create a sorted version of that array called `sorted`, then to search `distances` for the lowest three numbers in `sorted` to get the index from which you can look up the original number.

Comment: not homework, too old for that, Just a newb question. -- I gathered most of what you wrote from previous research, but what I can't figure out is how to get the index from the original array. Do I need to use key/values in the `distances` where the key is the distance and the value is the original index in the array? Or am I missing something more obvious?

Comment: @REDMX: It's helpful to include a summary of your research or snippets of code, even if they don't work, in the body of your question, so that answerers don't end up re-hashing what you already know and can give more pertinent, focused information. That's why I asked "What have you tried so far?"

Comment: @REDMX: see my revised answer. I make an array of indexes and sort that by the distance of the numbers to the search value. The method returns an array with the first three items of the array with values. The array contains the **indexes** of the 3 nearest values. No need for an array of dictonaries or some such, since the returned indexes (as NSNumbers) directly link to the values.

Comment: You get the indexes by searching "distances"  The indexes will be the same as in the original array.

Answer (score 0):

**Tested Code: 100 % works**

```
NSMutableArray *arrayWithNumbers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7],[NSNumber numberWithInt:23],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],[NSNumber numberWithInt:18],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],nil];

NSLog(@"arrayWithNumbers : %@ \n\n",arrayWithNumbers);





NSMutableArray *ResultArray = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *lowestArray = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *tempArray = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *indexArray = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSNumber *numberToFind=[NSNumber numberWithInt:5];

int limitToFilter = 3;


    for (NSNumber *number in arrayWithNumbers) {

        int a=[number intValue]-[numberToFind intValue];

        [lowestArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:abs(a)]];


    }

tempArray=[lowestArray mutableCopy];

NSSortDescriptor *LowestTohighest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];

[lowestArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:LowestTohighest]];

int upto = limitToFilter-[ResultArray count];

for (int i = 0; i < upto; i++) {


    [lowestArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([tempArray containsObject:[lowestArray objectAtIndex:i]]) {


        NSUInteger index=[tempArray indexOfObject:[lowestArray objectAtIndex:i]];



        [ResultArray addObject:[arrayWithNumbers objectAtIndex:index]];


        [indexArray addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:index]];



    }

}

NSLog(@"ResultArray is : %@ \n\n",ResultArray);

NSLog(@"indexArray is : %@ \n\n",indexArray);


    //here release all 4 arrays if u dont need them
```

**OUTPUT:**

arrayWithNumbers : (
                    7,
                    23,
                    4,
                    11,
                    18,
                    2
                    )

ResultArray is : (
                  4,
                  7,
                  2
                  )

indexArray is : (

```
    "<NSIndexSet: 0x4e06620>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (2)]",

    "<NSIndexSet: 0x4e04030>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (0)]",

    "<NSIndexSet: 0x4e06280>[number of indexes: 1 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (5)]"

        )
```